# Exception action when condition isn't met

Tags: exception, tcl, expect

Im trying to make an except script that will take action only if a string is NOT present on the command execution: example:

```
send -- "sys set -nd\r"
expect "showdebugcommands" {} "\n$PROMPT" {send -- "sys set showdebugcommands 1\r"}
```

What i want to do is: Do NOTHING if "showdebugcommands" is present on cmd output but in case it doesn't, execute command "sys set showdebugcommands 1".

How can i accomplish this using expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
set seen false
expect {
    "showdebugcommands" {set seen true; exp_continue}
    "\n$PROMPT" 
}
if { ! $seen} {
     send -- "sys set showdebugcommands 1\r"
}
```

Comment: Thanks glenn! I don't know why, the IF statement isn't triggering when the "showdebugcommands" word is present after the cmd execution. Anything i could be missing?

Comment: Isn't that what you want? You said you wanted to do nothing if that word is seen.

Comment: Ops. was my bad. Capitalization... thanks for the help. worked great.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by nesting an `expect` inside an `expect`. This is perfectly legal.

```
send -- "sys set -nd\r"
expect {
    "showdebugcommands" {
        expect "\n$PROMPT"
    }
    "\n$PROMPT" {
        send -- "sys set showdebugcommands 1\r"
        expect "\n$PROMPT"
    }
}
```

The aim is to drain the activity back to the known state (prompt showing) after seeing the thing that you wanted. It's always a good idea to think in terms of code units that take things back to a known state. (Because of that, I also added another `expect` of the prompt after the inner `send`; let's get it all back to the state of “I've just seen a prompt” at the end of the outer `expect` since that's the least crazy option.)